# keys and Values output - Python Collections

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(list,
            {'./lec5.pdf': ['social'],
             './some 3.pdf': ['social']})

a.values()
Out[10]: dict_values([['social'], ['social'], []]) # One empty list at last

a.keys()
Out[11]: dict_keys(['./social', './some 3.pdf', 0]) #O at last
```

I want to understand from where an empty list([]) is created inside  a.values() and for a.keys() 0 is created inside.

Comment: This code does not give that output.

Comment: What is the content of list ?
If it is an empty list: There is your answer

Comment: @Sharku: `list` is part of `defaultdict` usage and not an input list you are talking about.

Comment: @RishuA please provide reproducible sample.

Comment: I have changed the content inside , seems thats why you are not able to get the same output like myself, Give me sometime will provide you almost similar kind of dict..

Comment: @RishuA it looks like you are missing an `a[0]` statement before you call `keys()` and `values()`. This causes a new empty list to be created with the key `0`.

Comment: Python 2.7 output for a.values() is: [['social'], ['social']]

Comment: Somehow I am not able to reproduce same output again, I am trying few combinations , once I get that will provide that input and output. @AndriyIvaneyko

Comment: @RishuA that's great since it means there are no problem anymore :)

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Still can't say , I need to figure it out how it came , as this is a long code and created collection dict based on multiple scenarios. Will update here once I get it again with the same input ..

Answer (score -1):

I used python3 and results isn't the same:

```
import collections

a = collections.defaultdict(list,
        {'./lec5.pdf': ['social'],
         './some 3.pdf': ['social']})

a.values()
Out[0]:dict_values([['social'], ['social']])

a.keys()
Out[1]:dict_keys(['./lec5.pdf', './some 3.pdf'])
```

Try to rerun your code.

Comment: Yes, the same in Python-2.7, see above my comment.

Answer (score -1):

First the answer to your question:
You can initialize dictionaries in python much easier:

```
a = {'./lec5.pdf': ['social'],
    './some 3.pdf': ['social']}

print(a.values())
   out: dict_values([['social'], ['social']])
print(a.keys())
   out: dict_keys(['./lec5.pdf', './some 3.pdf'])
```

As your need for help I would suggest creating a List out of all files to be saved in a directory and than create the directory and loop over the list creating or copy each file.

Comment: that is the output of some collections that i saved in `a`